# If-statement in RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I have a vast list of chemicals for that I need to extract the CAS number. I have written a `for` loop which works as intended. However, when a chemical name is not found on the website, my code obviously stops.

Is there a way to account for this in the for loop? So that when a search query is not found, the loop goes back to the start page and searches for the next item in the list?

Down below is my code for the `for` loop with a short list of names to search for:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)

# start the server

rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
                             verbose = FALSE,
                             port = 4847L) # change number if port is not open

# create a client object
remDrCh <- rs_driver_object$client

items <- c("MCPA", "DEET", "apple")
numbers <- list()
for (i in items) {
  Sys.sleep(2)
  remDrCh$navigate("https://commonchemistry.cas.org/")
  search_box <- remDrCh$findElement(using = 'class', 'search-input')
  search_box$sendKeysToElement(list(paste(i), key = 'enter'))
  Sys.sleep(2)
  result <- remDrCh$findElement(using = "class", "result-content")
  result$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(2)
  cas <- remDrCh$findElements(using = 'class', 'cas-registry-number')
  cas_n <- lapply(cas, function (x) x$getElementText()) 
  numbers[[i]] <- unlist(cas_n)
  Sys.sleep(2)
  remDrCh$navigate("https://commonchemistry.cas.org/")
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

The problem lies in the `result <- remDrCh$findElement(using = "class", "result-content")` part. For "apple" there is no result, and thus no element that R could use.

I tried to write a separate `if else` argument for that specific part, but to no avail.
This still only works for queries that yield a result. I also tried to use `findElements` but this only helps for the case when no result is found.

```
result <- remDrCh$findElement(using = "class", "result-content")
if (length(result) > 0) {
  result$clickElement()
} else {
  remDrCh$navigate("https://commonchemistry.cas.org/")
}
```

I also tried to use this [How to check if an object is visible in a webpage by using its xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144108/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-visible-in-a-webpage-by-using-its-xpath) but I cannot get it to work on my example.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```r
items <- c("MCPA", "apple", "DEET")
numbers <- list()
for (i in items) {
  Sys.sleep(2)
  remDrCh$navigate("https://commonchemistry.cas.org/")
  search_box <- remDrCh$findElement(using = 'class', 'search-input')
  search_box$sendKeysToElement(list(paste(i), key = 'enter'))
  Sys.sleep(2)
  result <- try(remDrCh$findElement(using = "class", "result-content"))
  if(!inherits(result, "try-error")){
  result$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(2)
  cas <- remDrCh$findElements(using = 'class', 'cas-registry-number')
  cas_n <- lapply(cas, function (x) x$getElementText()) 
  numbers[[i]] <- unlist(cas_n)
  }else{
    numbers[[i]] <- NA
  }
  Sys.sleep(2)
  remDrCh$navigate("https://commonchemistry.cas.org/")
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

Note the `try()` wrapper around the problematic code:

```r
  result <- try(remDrCh$findElement(using = "class", "result-content"))
```

This will capture the error if there is one, but allow the loop to continue.  Then, there is an `if` statement that tries to find the result if the output from `try` is not of class `"try-error"` otherwise, it returns the number as `NA`.